# Vimeo embed - black screen on IE & FF

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player

I am having a stange behaviour with Vimeo, and I don't get what's going on...

I uploaded a couple videos, using a "plus" account". Everything worked out fine. BUT... Then I wanted to embed the videos in another website. Using the official "Iframe" method. And all I get on page load, is a black screen, instead of the video thumbnail... When I start playing the video, it works, but on load, all I get is that black screen.... It is like that visibly on browsers using the flash version (FF & IE) but I do get the good thumb on non-flash players (like chrome).

Am I doing something wrong ? What's even more strange, is that if I take any other video, not mine, and embed, it works perfectly, I get the thumb.

My video, Embedded : http://www.unpeuplusnet.fr/embed.html

Thanks for any possible help, my website should go live tomorrow !!

Bruno

Edit : I just tried using the old Flash embed version, it does not work any better...

http://www.unpeuplusnet.fr/embed2.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was a bug on our end. Should be working fine now. I'd recommend keeping the iframe embed.